# Generative Adversarial Network and Variational Autoencoders for Independent Component Analysis?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, variational-bayes, generative-models

**Background**:
I'm working on a model for independent component analysis (ICA) that is based on a methodology similar to GANs and VAEs. What I'm having trouble understanding is how the choice of the loss function affects the manner in which the factors produced by the model will approximate the true generative factors. The number of true factors is assumed to be unknown to the model performing the ICA.

**Questions**:
Is there a characterization of how, say, the KL divergence vs the earth mover distance causes the encoding of a VAE to change? Are there any similarities to something like L2 in ridge vs L1 regularization in LASSO regression? Are GANs really doing a similar type of 'latent factor' search, or is there not that much similarity to the interpretation?